# How to make Weakrefernce in Concurrent HashMap

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection, weak-references, java.util.concurrent

In my Program I have a scenario, where Mutiple Thread will operate (put and get) on a single Map. Like Thread a using put a key/value in the map and the same time another thread is retrieving the key/value from the map for the same or different key. Now if I make my map synchronize then it wil be a big performance issue, so I decided to move to ConcurrentHashMap. During this scenario, I have another complexity that after certain period of time(not known to my application) few of the key/value pairs are not needed in my application, so I need to remove the same(Garbage Collection) to free memory. Though my programm doesn't have the idea that which key/values are not needed I thought to use weakrefernce. So, after ceratin period of time if the key(String) is not reachable it will be automatically garbage collected. I know the process to do the same in WeakhashMap but doesn't know the process to do it in ConcurrentHashMap. So, can anyone tell me how to do a weakrefernce in ConcurrentHashMap. Or else is there any other way to achieve the above scenario?

Comment: [look this reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456742/concurrenthashmap-with-weak-keys-and-identity-hash) May be it's help)

Comment: How to instantiate a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap with WeakReference

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the `WeakHashMap` code it seems that there is no straight forward way of doing this but something of this following form should work: (This code has not actually been tested but I think it is at least on the correct path, also it only implements put and get, other operations can likewise be implemented)

```
public class MyMap<K, V> {

    private class MyKey<K> extends WeakReference<K> {         

        private final int hashCode;

        private MyKey(K k, ReferenceQueue<K> q) {
            super(k, q);
            hash = k.hashCode();
        }

        private MyKey(K k) {
            super(k);
            hash = k.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hashCode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof MyKey)) {
                return false;
            }

            K otherKey = ((MyKey<K>) o).get();
            K myKey = get();
            if (otherKey != null && key != null) {
                return otherKey.equals(myKey);
            }

            return this == o;
        }
    }

    private final Map<MyKey<K>, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<MyKey<K>, V>();
    private final ReferenceQueue<K> queue = new ReferenceQueue<K>();

    public V put(K key, V val) {
        expungeStaleEntries();
        return map.put(new MyKey<K>(key, queue), val);    
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        expungeStaleEntries();
        return map.get(new MyKey<K>(key));
    }

    private void expungeStaleEntries() {
        MyKey<K> key = null;
        while ((key = (MyKey<K>) queue.poll()) != null) {
            map.remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Potential incorrectness of the above code aside, another caveat is that `WeakHashMap` works by calling its own `expungeStaleEntries()` method every time you call things like `put()`, `get()`, or even `size()`. The problem with this in the current scenario however is that `ReferenceQueue.poll()` does the actual polling inside of a `synchronized` block so cleaning up can slow you down (however it will not lock if the queue is empty so it will not undo all of the speed-improvement work `ConcurrentHashMap` is doing).